# What is the SQL Server equivalent of this Oracle query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to run analytical function in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791559/unable-to-run-analytical-function-in-sql-server)

I have been trying to run an analytical function in SQL server but I'm having difficulty.

Here is my query in Oracle syntax, which works well:

```
SELECT 
    TEAM_ID, 
    LEVEL_ID, 
    FF_ID, 
    MODULE_ID, 
    TERR_ID, 
    MERGE_KEY,
    count(distinct TERR_ID) over (partition by TEAM_ID,LEVEL_ID,FF_ID,MODULE_ID)
    || ' of ' || 
    count(distinct TERR_ID) over (partition by TEAM_ID,LEVEL_ID,FF_ID) 
    as MISMATCH_TERR_COUNT_IN_FF 
FROM SCN7BBFE80210E04E2F88653A.PA83FB9BD57E044618B7AC86A;
```

But I'm getting an error when trying to do the same thing for SQL Server.

I created a table with columns `TEAM_ID`, `LEVEL_ID`, `FF_ID`, `MODULE_ID`, `TERR_ID`, and `MERGE_KEY`, and then inserted values into the table like so:

```
insert into PA83FB9BD57E044618B7AC86A values('3',1,'YH','PERF','3XBDA3',1)         
insert into PA83FB9BD57E044618B7AC86A values('3',1,'YH','PERF','3XAJA3',1)
```

Here is the query I'm using for SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
    TEAM_ID, 
    LEVEL_ID, 
    FF_ID, 
    MODULE_ID, 
    TERR_ID, 
    MERGE_KEY, 
    ISNULL(CAST(count(distinct TERR_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY TEAM_ID, LEVEL_ID, FF_ID, MODULE_ID) AS nvarchar(max)), '')
    + ' of ' + 
    ISNULL(CAST(count(distinct TERR_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY TEAM_ID, LEVEL_ID, FF_ID) AS nvarchar(max)), '') 
    AS MISMATCH_TERR_COUNT_IN_FF 
FROM dbo.PA83FB9BD57E044618B7AC86A
```

When I try to run this query, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:Incorrect syntax near 'distinct'.
```

I tried to create a minimal query that gives the same error, and I came up with this:

```
SELECT 
    TEAM_ID, 
    LEVEL_ID, 
    FF_ID, 
    MODULE_ID, 
    TERR_ID, 
    MERGE_KEY, 
    cast(count(distinct TERR_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY TEAM_ID, LEVEL_ID, FF_ID, MODULE_ID)
    AS MISMATCH_TERR_COUNT_IN_FF
FROM dbo.PA83FB9BD57E044618B7AC86A
```

And I still get the error:

```
ERROR:Incorrect syntax near 'distinct'
```

I also tried removing the `cast()` part as well, but the same error always appears.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the issue here may be the use of `PARTITION BY`. As far as I know, SQL Server has no direct equivalent of this feature. In general, Oracle PL/SQL and Microsoft T-SQL have many incompatible features, so it's not always possible to get the same behavior from both of them.

Comment: @DanielPryden - This is incorrect. SQL Server most certainly does have `partition by` and `over`. As I answered this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791559/unable-to-run-analytical-function-in-sql-server/8791603#8791603 , SQL Server cannot do `count(distinct col)` when the `count` is part of an `over` clause.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `count(distinct ...) over(...)` is not supported in at least SQL Server 2005 & 2008. See last reply at https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/254393/over-clause-enhancement-request-distinct-clause-for-aggregate-functions

I did not find a reference as to whether this is supported in 2008 R2.