# Unable to run analytical function in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, database

In Oracle it works well. Query for oracle is As Follows

```
SELECT TEAM_ID, LEVEL_ID, FF_ID, MODULE_ID, TERR_ID, MERGE_KEY, count(distinct TERR_ID) over (partition by TEAM_ID,LEVEL_ID,FF_ID,MODULE_ID)||' of '||count(distinct TERR_ID) over (partition by TEAM_ID,LEVEL_ID,FF_ID) as MISMATCH_TERR_COUNT_IN_FF FROM SCN7BBFE80210E04E2F88653A.PA83FB9BD57E044618B7AC86A;
```

But for SQL Server, I'm getting an error

I created table with columnname as TEAM_ID, LEVEL_ID, FF_ID, MODULE_ID, TERR_ID, MERGE_KEY then inserted values into the table ...

```
insert into PA83FB9BD57E044618B7AC86A values('3',1,'YH','PERF','3XBDA3',1)
insert into PA83FB9BD57E044618B7AC86A values('3',1,'YH','PERF','3XAJA3',1)
```

This is the SQL query ...

```
SELECT  TEAM_ID ,
        LEVEL_ID ,
        FF_ID ,
        MODULE_ID ,
        TERR_ID ,
        MERGE_KEY ,
        ISNULL(CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT TERR_ID) OVER ( PARTITION BY TEAM_ID,
                                 LEVEL_ID, FF_ID, MODULE_ID ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),
               '') + ' of '
        + ISNULL(CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT TERR_ID) OVER ( PARTITION BY TEAM_ID,
                                 LEVEL_ID, FF_ID ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),
                 '') AS MISMATCH_TERR_COUNT_IN_FF
FROM    dbo.PA83FB9BD57E044618B7AC86A
```

Above query when run give ERROR:Incorrect syntax near 'distinct'.

making Query small i tried

```
SELECT TEAM_ID, LEVEL_ID, FF_ID, MODULE_ID, TERR_ID, MERGE_KEY, cast(count(distinct TERR_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY TEAM_ID, LEVEL_ID, FF_ID, MODULE_ID) AS MISMATCH_TERR_COUNT_IN_FF FROM dbo.PA83FB9BD57E044618B7AC86A
```

ERROR:Incorrect syntax near 'distinct'

i tried by removing Cast part as well but same error appear again n again

Can anybody help .......

Comment: Please clean up the line breaks.  I added code tags but I'm not going to parse through that whole thing for you to add breaks and spacing.

Comment: I did the SQL using SQL Prompt, but his second SQL query isn't valid ...

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a `count(distinct col)` in an `over` clause. You'll have to do a subquery that does the `count(distinct col)` with an old-fashioned `group by` to do what you want to do.

Comment: See: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/254393/over-clause-enhancement-request-distinct-clause-for-aggregate-functions for official word on `count(distinct ...) over (...)` not being supported.